# Auto convert dot `.` to arrow `->` in C/C++?

Tags: flycheck, c++

I'm using `flycheck` in `cc-mode` and it reminds me when I'm typing:

`member reference type 'ListNode *' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?`

I want to know if there's any package can convert `.` into `->` automatically when typing in C/C++ code, just like Qt Creator's default behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Not completely automatic, but `flycheck-ycmd` supports that because it uses Clang under the hood and Clang's fix-its are available from Emacs.

Position the point under the variable, just do `M-x ycmd-fixit` and accept the proposed fix-it.

You can disable the prompt before applying a fix-it by eval'ing

`(setq ycmd-confirm-fixit nil)`